# How can I find coordinates of distorted point using Imagemagick?

Tags: computer-vision, imagemagick, distortion, camera-distortion

I am using Imagemagick to distort the full image, but I have some problem with determination of distorted position of the single point from original image.

I am working with Barrel Inverse distortion right now and from Imagemagick documentation I see that distorted position is determined with the following equation:

[Barrel Inverse Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCuFB.png)

What I want to achieve: given pair of original image coordinates (X<sub>src</sub>, Y<sub>src</sub>) and the set of Barrel Inverse distortion coefficients (A, B, C, D) determine pair of coordinates for target image (X<sub>tgt</sub>, Y<sub>tgt</sub>).

From the equation above I can't tell the correct way to implement mapping.

Comment: Can you upload your image as well and provide values for X, Y (src) and A,B,C,D. Also, do you need mapping of a specific location or just corrected image. As per https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/lens/#non-scaling correction can be done via `convert distorted_image.jpg -distort barrel "A B C" corrected_image.jpg`

Comment: You need the inverse transform, which is not easily done.